# error net_rim_bb_browser_field_api when download blackberry file

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, ota

I had this error when downloading a blackberry app from a webserver, as I make the user download it over the air:

> this appication requires the following module : net_rim_bb_browser_field_api

I had created my app with blackberry - eclipse and uploaded .cod and .jad files from **deliverables\Web** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most probable reason is your application has been compiled with newer SDK than it is supported by your device.

Please note that BlackBerry device RIM OS version has to be equal or bigger than java SDK version you have used upon compilation of your application.

For instance, if you have used RIM BlackBerry java SDK version 5.0, then your application will run on the devices with RIM OS version: 5.0, 6.x, 7.x.

It won't run on devices with RIM OS older than 5.0 (versions 4.6, 4.5, 4.3, etc).

And it won't run on new BB 10 platform. But there is another reason. BB 10 is not compatible with RIM java SDK for BlackBerry.

You get your error because code of the downloading application has references to a class, located in `net_rim_bb_browser_field_api` module, which is not present on your blackberry device.